# Is there any difference between using CRUD and Queries through code?

Tags: node.js, express, crud

Is there any significant difference between use just query through nodeJS code like this:

```
const {Client} = require('pg');
const client = new Client ({
    user:"postgres",
    password:"123456",
    host:"localhost",
    port:5432,
    database:"nodeapp"
})

client.connect()
.then(()=>console.log("Connected succsefully"))
.then(()=>client.query(`INSERT INTO public.users(id, name, phone) VALUES (3, 'sdasd', '012312132132323123');`)) //post vs query ?
.then(()=>client.query("SELECT * FROM users"))
.then((results)=>console.table(results.rows))
.catch((e)=>console.log(e))
.finally(()=>client.end())
```

or CRUD with the express package like this:

```
app.post('/user',(req,res)=>{
    const {body} = req,
    {id,name,phone} = body,
    q = `INSERT INTO public.users(
        id, name, phone)
        VALUES (${id}, '${name}', '${phone}');`
       // debugger;
    db.query(q,(err,dbRes)=>{
            if(err)
            res.status(400).send(err)

            else
             res.send({
                 id,name,phone
             })
        })
})
```

In these tWo examples I get the same result, should I use CRUD with express? Does that matter?

Comment: What is the context around the first code? It has hardcoded values. What difference specifically you want help on?

Comment: @tbking I changed to the "full" code. I just want to know if the first example also considers as CRUD, or there any difference between them in something - security , range of option, or anything. I just want to know if there is any.

Comment: Are you using sequelize middleware in the 2nd example?

Comment: express and pg packages @KaseyChang

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first approach in using Promises and the second one is using callbacks. Either approach is fine. Although, I see in your second approach there is a "db" object that is reused(Which is a good practice). Don't keep reconnecting, use the same connection for all operations

Comment: "Is there any significant difference between use just query through nodeJS code like this:" "or CRUD with the express package like this:" this isn't answering the question, this is explaining the difference between a Promise and a callback.

Answer (score 0):

CRUD = Create, Read, Update, Delete

These are operations commonly found within your database. Your second example, is a way of executing those operations, remotely.

The second example uses Express to expose an endpoint `/user` that you can access to complete the query. The way you provide data is using the body of a HTTP request.

The first example isn't dynamic, it's a hardcoded query you can only call from one place, doing only one thing.

You can't access the first example from anywhere (other than your application), so if you need it elsewhere then you can't.

Also, if you haven't got your query inside a function, you can't access that either later.

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/
- https://medium.com/@TebbaVonMathenstien/what-is-an-api-and-why-should-i-use-one-863c3365726b
- https://www.perforce.com/blog/qac/challenge-code-reuse-and-how-reuse-code-effectively
- https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/
- https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-crud (What is CRUD? - useful)

TL;DR: the second option is the similar to using `import/export`, instead of exporting a method, you export(expose) an endpoint, you then `import` that endpoint using a HTTP request: `http://localhost:3000/v1/users/123` with a GET method would be the same as:

```js
function getUser(userId) {
  // REALLY THIS IS YOUR MYSQL QUERY
  return {
    userId,
    username: 'user'
  }
}

const user = getUser(123);
console.log(user);
```

Comment: But if I use for example `${variable}` it's becoming dynamic as well, am I wrong? And can't I just do the same with the first option -> require and exports for using it in other places?

Comment: @Yopi I've updated my original answer, I hope that explains it in a more understandable way.